# What is 'では‘ and how is it used?

Tags: grammar, usage, word-usage

I've been going on a Japanese course and I don't understand the grammar behind 'dewa'. I've seen it being used in 私はおちゃとこひがすきではありません and 私はにほんじんではありません　and I don't completely understand its use in grammar and definition. Is it the negative desu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that ではありません is the negative form of です. At this stage I think you should just understand it as a single unit rather than looking at では and ありません separately. But [See this link](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23542/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84vs-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84vs%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84).

You will also see じゃありません (じゃ is a contraction of では) and じゃない (ない is the informal form of ありません) with decreasing levels of formality.

Note that it can be used to negate nouns and na-adjectives (as in your two examples), but **not** i-adjectives and verbs.

Answer (score 0):

First「私はおちゃと"こひ"がすきではありません」should be 「私はおちゃと"コーヒー"がすきではありません」.

「私はおちゃと"コーヒー"がすきではありません」=　negative expression of「私はおちゃと"コーヒー"がすきです」

To make the sentnce negative, we change the phrase "（すき）です" into negative one.

"（すき）です" + "ない" => "（すき）です＋ない" =>　"（すき）ではない"