# Difference between ではありません and ありません

Tags: negation, copula

Difference between ではありません and ありません. When do I need to add the では in front of ありません?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/23542/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84vs-%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84vs%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84. Both used for negation "no" or "neither".

Comment: Why did you tag this question with [tag:colloquial-language]?

Answer (score 2):

> ではありません

is meant to express something isn't, while

> ありません

is meant to express the lack of or nonexistence of something (if concrete, something immobile).

> 学校ではありません。 (It's) not a school.
>
> 学校ありません。 There's no school.

Answer (score 1):

ありません is the negative polite form of あります. You use it to describe that something "doesn't exist". Ex.:

ここに車がありません。
There are no cars here.

ではありません on the other hand, acts as the negative form of です. Ex.:

私は猫ではありません。
I'm not a cat.